# How to bind service to port 80 on the host, while using CNI

Tags: kubernetes

I'm trying to bind a service to port 80 on the host, but I'm using CNI. So 
`hostPort` won't work. `NodePort` will only allow port 30000-32000. And I don't have access to a cloud LB.

Thanks

Comment: the question is not clear enough, do you mind adding more details of what you have tried and what do you mean by I am using CNI etc.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think in this case you need to setup the some revese proxy (haproxy or nginix) to redirect port 80 taffic on the node to service ip.

Comment: Do you mean like ingress? Because I've tried to deploy ingress with nginx but it also runs off of NodePort. Or do you mean to run a proxy on host and forward traffic to the nodeport that my service is listening to?

Comment: run the nginx on the host and direct the traffic to `NodeIP:ServerPort`